# No se registran los datos en formulario

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Hola tengo un pequeño código de registro de usuarios pero no me esta insertando los datos en base de datos:

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','coco');
?>
```

**formulario.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilos.css">
    <title>Registro CocoBaby</title>
</head>
<body background="images/golf.jpg" style="background-attachment: fixed" >
    <center><div class="tit"><h2 style="color: #0000FF; ">Registro</h2>
<br>
    <!-- formulario registro -->

<form method="post" action="" >
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="font-size: 14pt"><b>Ingresa tu nombre</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="realname" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="font-size: 14pt; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>Ingresa tu email</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="nick" class="form-control"  required placeholder="Ingresa mail"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="font-size: 14pt; color: #FFFFFF;"><b>Ingresa tu Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control"  placeholder="Ingresa contraseña" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="font-size: 14pt"><b>Repite tu contraseña</b></label>
            <input type="password" name="rpass" class="form-control" required placeholder="repite contraseña" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <input  class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrarse"/><br><br>
    <a href="./index.php"><input  class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Ya tengo Cuenta"/></a>

  </fieldset>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        require("./valogin/registro.php");
    }
?>
<!--Fin formulario registro -->
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

**./valogin/registro.php**

```
<?php

$realname=$_POST['realname'];
$mail=$_POST['nick'];
$pass= $_POST['pass'];
$rpass=$_POST['rpass'];

require("conexion.php");
$checkemail=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='$mail'");
$check_mail=mysqli_num_rows($checkemail);
    if($pass==$rpass){
        if($check_mail>0){
            echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Atencion, ya existe el mail designado para un usuario, verifique sus datos");</script> ';
        }else{
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login VALUES('','$realname','$pass','$mail','','2')");
            echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script> ';

        }

    }else{
        echo 'Las contraseñas son incorrectas';
    }
?>
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal ? :(

Les agredeceria la ayuda :)

Comment: Te da algún error?

Comment: No ni eso, me arroja mi propio script que si se registró pero no guarda los datos en la bd

Comment: ha simple vista párese un error tipográfico, te falta los `()` luego de `login`, `INSERT INTO login() VALUES(' ',' ',...)`

Comment: Lo mejor sería que reescribas el insert con prepared statements incluso por motivos de seguridad. Pero para ver si no se está confundiendo con el apostrofe ('), en lugar de dejar las variables dentro del string con "", concatenalas con . (punto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He intentando observar un control estricto de tu código, es decir, controlar lo que pasa en cada momento e imprimir mensajes que indiquen lo que está ocurriendo. Es bueno hacer eso siempre, así sabremos sin demasiada dificultad lo que está pasando.

El código que sigue no hace ningún cambio en tu formulario HTML.

Sí introduce cambios en el código PHP:

- Usa consultas preparadas para manejar los datos con más seguridad
- Controla el estado de cada variable
- Reorganiza un poco los `if ... then...` por ejemplo, en el código original tú preguntas primero si `if($pass==$rpass){ ...`  y luego preguntas `if($check_mail>0){...` yo lo hago la verificación al mismo tiempo.

Bueno aquí va, espero te sirva. Hay comentarios para aclarar los posibles puntos dudosos.

```
$realname=$_POST['realname'];
$mail=$_POST['nick'];
$pass= $_POST['pass'];
$rpass=$_POST['rpass'];

require("conexion.php");

/*Escribir SELECT en consulta preparada usando marcadores de posición (?)*/
$sql="SELECT * FROM login WHERE email=?";

/*Preparar la consulta*/

$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);

/*Evaluar si  la preparación tuvo  éxito*/

if (!$stmt) 
{
    echo "Hubo fallo preparando el SELECT";

}else{

     /*
       * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
       * la letra "s" indica el tipo de cada dato que se va a pasar
       * s: String, si es una cadena , i: Integer, si fuera un entero, etc
       * Ejecutar
    */

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $mail);
    $stmt->execute();

    /*Verificar si la consulta arrojó algún resultado*/

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0 && ($pass==$rpass)) {

        echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Atencion, ya existe el mail designado para un usuario, verifique sus datos");</script> ';

    }else{

        /*
         * Escribir consulta INSERT de forma segura
         * Yo escribiría el INSERT indicando explícitamente las columnas implicadas
         * ejemplo: INSERT INTO (realname, pass, email, otracolumna) VALUES (?,?,?,?); 
         * imagino que el valor '2' no es del tipo INT en la tabla, si lo es debería ir sin las comillas simples     
        */

        $sql="INSERT INTO login VALUES('',?,?,?,'','2')");

        /*Preparar la consulta */            
        $stmt=$con->prepare($sql);

        /*Evaluar si  la preparación tuvo  éxito*/

        if (!$stmt) 
        {

            echo "Hubo fallo preparando el INSERT";

        }else{

             /*
               * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
               * las letras "sss" indica el tipo de cada dato que se va a pasar
               * s: String, si es una cadena , i: Integer, si fuera un entero, etc
               * Ejecutar
            */

            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $realname,$pass,$mail);
            $stmt->execute();

            /*Evaluar si hubo inserción de filas*/

            if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0)
            {

                echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script>';

            }else{

                echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("No fue posible realizar la inserción");</script> ';

            }

        echo "Hubo un error al preparar la consulta de inserción";

        }

    echo 'Las contraseñas son incorrectas';

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto hazlo de nuevo desde el principio, este codigo funciona

**HTML PARA INSERTAR**

```
   <input name="cod"    name="codigo" required>
   <input name="nom"    name="nombre" required>
   <input name="apelli" name="apellido" required>
   <input name="ed"     name="edad" required>
                               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insertar">
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      require("insertar.php");
    }
  ?>




    </body>



------------------------------
```

> **insertar.php**

```
    <?php
    $codd=$_POST['cod'];
    $apelll=$_POST['nom'];
    $nomm= $_POST['apelli'];
    $edd=$_POST['ed'];



                require("conexion.php");
        if($codd>0){


                require("conexion.php");
                $sql = "INSERT INTO alumnos (id, nombre, apellidos, edad) 
                        VALUES ('".$codd."','".$apelll."','".$nomm."','".$edd."');";

                $query_new_user_insert = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
                echo 'Se ha registrado con exito';
                echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("Usuario registrado con éxito");</script> ';


            }else{
            echo ' <script language="javascript">alert("deben ingresar un codigo");</script> ';
        }



?>
```

---

Comment: Ok lo checaré :)

Comment: Solo quitale name

Comment: Okas ahora checo

Comment: name  name   name... lo agregue dos vesces .Bendiciones

Comment: <form method="post" action="" >

   <input name="cod">
   <input name="nom">
   <input name="apelli">
   <input name="ed">
                               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="insertar">
</form>

Comment: Okas ahora checo 